# View source does not show html source in cognos

Tags: html, cognos, view-source

In Cognos viewer, when the report is rendered in html format, in IE, it looks like any html page. But when I do a 'View Source', how come I do not see the  html in the view source? is there a way to turn it on?

Comment: I am not familiar with cognos, but regardless you should be able to view source of any page you are viewing. Some browser's view source is limited especially if content is loaded via javascript after the page has been created. If you have firefox -- you can make a selection on the page and "view selection source" which will reveal the source regardless if it was generated after page-load.

Comment: Thanks. But in firefox, when i right click on the page, i do not see 'View Selection Source'. I see 'View Page Source' and in my case when n i click it, it does not show me the full source? just the js file imports :(

Comment: You don't see "view selection source" when you select specific elements on the page? That option will be invisible until a selection is made.